# Pandas - AttributeError: '_iLocIndexer' object has no attribute 'sector'

Tags: python, pandas

I've built a sample code, to see if things worked as I wanted.

```
predictorgroups=predictor.groupby("sector")
targetco=target.iloc[1]
group=predictorgroups.get_group(targetco.sector).astype(object)
pdf=(group).sort('size',ascending=False)[:10].astype(object)
```

It worked fine. So I wanted to upgrade and make that code interact multiple times, so I adapted it to:

```
for i in range(len(target.index[:10])):
    predictorgroups=predictor.groupby("sector")
    targetco=target.iloc(i)
    group=predictorgroups.get_group(targetco.sector).astype(object)
    pdf=(group).sort('size',ascending=False)[:10].astype(object)
```

Note that this one is the very same code as the above. However in the second one I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/file.py", line 64, in <module>
group=predictorgroups.get_group(targetco.sector).astype(object)
AttributeError: '_iLocIndexer' object has no attribute 'sector'
```

I noticed that in the first code, if I print `targetco` I get a Pandas Series with only one index. If I do the same in the second one, I get the following object type:

`targetco pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer object at 0x105a3e438`

Can anyone explain to me why is that happening? Why I'm getting a different response in the second code if they are both the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is typo, change `()` to `[]`:

```
targetco=target.iloc(i)
```

to

```
targetco=target.iloc[i]
```

Because:

```
targetco = target.iloc(1)
print (targetco)
<pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer object at 0x000000000A8CD358>
```

and then `pandas.core.indexing._iLocIndexer` object has no column `sector`, so raise error:

```
print (targetco.sector)
AttributeError: '_iLocIndexer' object has no attribute 'sector'
```